# Raspberry Pi Zero Picamera

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, picamera

My Picamera V1.3 is not detected

```
 vcgencmd get_camera
```

prints...

```
supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=1
```

But I can capture imgs and video per libcamera...

Since I want to use either the picamera or the cv2 python library to record video, I ' m always getting the "no camera detected" issue.

Has someone a good idea how I can get the cam detected ?
I really have no idea how to resolve that issue !

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have the legacy mode disabled in your settings, which should prevent you from using the picamera module, not sure if it also prevents open-cv from using it.

to enable legacy camera:

1. Ensure your system is up-to-date and reboot it.
2. Run sudo raspi-config .
3. Navigate to Interface Options and select Legacy camera to enable it.
4. Reboot your Raspberry Pi again.

PS. if you run your Pi headless with the legacy camera disabled (via VNC) you may get the error: cannot currently show desktop. To fix this can force HDMI hot plug. https://www.shellhacks.com/raspberry-pi-force-hdmi-hotplug/